# Wordpress "post_views_count" return 0 value

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I don't understand the behavior of the "post_views_count" directive.

I created a shortocode that should show me the most viewed posts of the last 2 years, from 2021 to today.

All posts from 2022 are completely ignored, while those from 2021 are printed on screen but show 0 as the value...

The blog on which I have put the feature to thousands of articles and has been very visited for years. I don't understand why this value is not seen by my query and in the best case it returns me 0.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing or I don't understand what post_views_count is for?

follow the code:

```
add_shortcode('lista_post_piu_visti', 'lista_post_most_viewed_fn');

function lista_post_most_viewed_fn($atts) {
$args_shortcode = shortcode_atts(array(
    'n_post' => '',
    'colore_titolo' => ''
        ), $atts);

$output = '';

$args_query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
           'after' => '2 January 2021'
        )
    )
);

$custom_posts = new WP_Query($args_query);

if ($custom_posts->have_posts()) {
    $all_posts = $custom_posts->found_posts;

    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) {
        $custom_posts->the_post();

      
        $riassunto = get_the_excerpt();
        $titolo = get_the_title();
        $url_articolo = get_the_permalink();

        $output .= '<div class="box_min">';
        $output .= '<div class="img_lat"><a href="' . $url_articolo . '" title="' . $titolo . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail') . '</a></div>';
        $output .= '<h2><a href="' . $url_articolo . '" title="' . $titolo . '">' . $titolo . '</a></h2>';

        $output .= '<h3>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true) . '</h3>';

        $output .= '<div class="autore-box"><span>' . get_the_date() . '</span></div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
 
}

$output = $output ?? '<strong class="alert">Sorry, no post found.</strong>';
return $output;
}

add_shortcode('lista_post_by_id_prima_in_evidenza', 'lista_post_by_id_prima_in_evidenza_fn');
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr `post_views_count` isn't standard.

According to your query in your sample code, you expect `post_views_count` to show up in wp_postmeta as an integer-valued item of post metadata with `meta_key =  'post_views_count'`.

But this item of metadata isn't inserted or maintained by anything in core WordPress. So, you must be using some plugin for the purpose. If you don't see anything for 2022, it's possible you discontinued using that plugin at the beginning of 2022.  And, you have zeros in that item for your 2021 posts.

At any rate, if your site hasn't been updating that metadata you won't be able to regenerate it except possibly from web server logs -- a painful task even if you have logs going that far back.  (And GDPR doesn't want you to store logs for that long.)

According to https://WPDirectory.net , [quite a few plugins](https://wpdirectory.net/search/01GTVEJZ8KF0DJS4SZNHY4Y38T) mention `post_views_meta`.  Which one do you use?